# TypeScript using node and browser env in the same project

Tags: node.js

I have a web project that has both server-side (node) and client-side (browser) components. In TypeScript node is typed in `node.d.ts` and for example defined require:

```
declare var require : NodeRequire;
```

but this is not correct when code is run in browser, when a better definition would be coming from `webpack-env`

```
declare var require : RequireFunction;
```

How do I tell `tsc` to use backend set of typing definition files for backend and frontend set of function definitions for frontend?